# How to export BLOB image(PNG) from SQLite to file or execl ?

Tags: sqlite, png, blob

The table is below :

create table symbols(
SymbolID integer not null,
PngData  BLOB
);

expect for your assist

Comment: What programming language?

Comment: the BLOB is stored in postgreSQL and I have solved the issue by python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way you can do it with some Perl. First I load a PNG image into the database, then I extract it into a file to show it worked.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;

my $myfile = "picture.png";
my $dbname = "test.db";
my $data;

# Connect to database
my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:SQLite:dbname=$dbname") || die "Cannot open db";

# >8 >8 >8  Cut starting here  >8 >8 >8 >8 >8

# Open the image file
open MYFILE, $myfile  or die "Cannot open file";

# Read in the file
while (<MYFILE>) {
   $data .= $_;
}
close MYFILE;

# Insert image into database
my $sql = "INSERT INTO symbols VALUES (1,?)";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
my $numrows = $sth->execute($data);
$sth->finish;

# >8 >8 >8  Cut ending here >8 >8 >8 >8 >8

#Now read it back and save as file
$sql = "SELECT PngData from symbols";
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$numrows = $sth->execute;

open OUTPUT, ">output.png";
my $ref = $sth->fetchrow_hashref;
my $newdata = $$ref{'PngData'};
print OUTPUT $newdata;
close OUTPUT;
$sth->finish;
$dbh->disconnect;
```

If you just want to extract the image BLOB from the database and save it as a file, use this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;

my $dbname = "test.db";
my ($sql,$sth,$numrows,$ref,$newdata);

# Connect to database
my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:SQLite:dbname=$dbname") || die "Cannot open db";

# Read image and save as file
$sql = "SELECT PngData from symbols";
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$numrows = $sth->execute;

open OUTPUT, ">output.png";
$ref = $sth->fetchrow_hashref;
$newdata = $$ref{'PngData'};
print OUTPUT $newdata;
close OUTPUT;
$sth->finish;
$dbh->disconnect;
```

If you want to create a database with sqlite, and play around with this code, then do this:

```
sqlite3 test.db "CREATE TABLE symbols(SymbolID integer,PngData BLOB);"
```

Comment: thank your detailed code, I could use my python refer to your mind